# debootstrap error while upgrading from 10.04 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, upgrade, debootstrap

I made a version upgrade with apt-get dist-upgrade and I had this error while upgrading packages:

```
2013-01-24 08:49:32 upgrade debootstrap 1.0.37ubuntu1~lucid1 1.0.39ubuntu0.2
2013-01-24 08:49:32 status half-installed debootstrap 1.0.37ubuntu1~lucid1
```

First I thought that the debootstrap package was corrupt so I cleaned the package cache an re-downloaded the updates and didn't worked.

Then I tried removing the previous version and then install this one of the package but I got this:

```
dpkg: error processing debootstrap (--remove):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 debootstrap
```

Now I'm stuck with a inconsistent OS because I cannot finish the upgrade because this package conflict is telling me to do a dpkg --configure -a that gets stuck in this:

```
Preparing to replace debootstrap 1.0.37ubuntu1~lucid1 (using.../debootstrap_1.0.39ubuntu0.2_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement debootstrap ...
```

So what can I do about this?

Comment: A `dpkg` process stuck at `Unpacking replacement` seems to indicate other issues: disk full, disk not responding, etc. Or, you're hitting [LP Bug #1085053: dpkg hangs installing debootstrap](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/1085053).